# Creating message rule

Tags: macos, outlook

I have a spam problem. I need help to create a rule in outlook, so that when identifying a text in the body of the email is sent to the trash.

I managed to make the settings, using the subject, but it always changes. The domain also always changes. The only thing that doesn't change is a link in the email.

Image:

[image]

Comment: try using regex - https://regex101.com/r/MaX6Dt/1

Comment: @0m3r, The link sent is offline.

Comment: @0m3r Thanks for the help, but where do I put this instruction in macOS outlook? Can you tell me the way?

Comment: You will have to write outlook vba